# When load a aspx into a div, the aspx cannot work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to load an  `test.aspx` page into a `div` in the `index.aspx` with `ajax`.

The code in `index.aspx`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDiv(name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async:true,
            url: '/index/innerAspx/' + name,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#mainPage").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The trigger event is `<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadDiv('test.aspx');">test</a></li>`

---

I load the test.aspx in `chrome`、`IE` and both work well.
I load `index.aspx` and try to load `test.aspx` into the `div` of `index.aspx` by click the `href test`.

- In IE, there is weird error
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDlIs.png)
- In Chrome, I can get  `test.aspx` in `div`, but there is a warning `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`.
  What's more, some function in `test.aspx` cannot work.

For example, there is a `treeview` and a `textbox`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         选择所属课程：<asp:TextBox ID="courseShow" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TreeView ID="courseTree" runat="server" CssClass="TreeView" OnSelectedNodeChanged="courseTree_SelectedNodeChanged">
         </asp:TreeView>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the function `courseTree_SelectedNodeChanged` there is only `courseShow.Text = courseTree.SelectedNode.Text;`.

If I load the `test.asp` separately, I can set the `text` of `textbox` by click the node of the `treeview`. But through `index.aspx`, I get the error when I click the node:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/migvJ.png)

I have tried set `async:true` and `async:false` in `.ajax`. The performance doesn't change!

What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: What about loading the aspx page into an iframe instead?

Comment: 1.I have tried iframe. But how to set the `width` and `height` of `iframe`  so as to act like load a `aspx` into `div`

Comment: 2. How could change the `src` of `iframe` by click a button in the current active `src` in `iframe` to another `src`

Comment: 3. I have another problem. I put the `test.aspx` in a `updatepanel`. I have tried put the `updatepanel` in `index.aspx`   containing the `div`. I tried put the `updatepanel` in `test.aspx` containing the whole `body`. But once I click a button in `test.aspx`, the whole page is refreshed. Is it because that `updatepanel` can't work in this situation?